# How to properly add persistence in docker-compose deployment including postgres and keycloak

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, keycloak

I am trying to create a persistent docker-compose deployment. Previously I have done so by simply mounting a local directory to a docker container. It worked fine. However, when I tried adding keycloak to the mix it generates errors.

Working compose file:

```
version: '3'

volumes:
  postgres_data:
      driver: local

services:
  postgres:
      image: postgres
      volumes:
        - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        - ./init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
      environment:
        POSTGRES_DB: keycloak
        POSTGRES_USER: keycloak
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      ports:
        - 5432:5432
  keycloak:
      image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest
      environment:
        DB_VENDOR: POSTGRES
        DB_ADDR: postgres
        DB_DATABASE: keycloak
        DB_USER: keycloak
        DB_SCHEMA: public
        DB_PASSWORD: password
        KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
        KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: admin
      ports:
        - 8080:8080
      depends_on:
        - postgres
```

Non-working compose file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  postgres:
      image: postgres
      volumes:
        - ./postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        - ./init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
      environment:
        POSTGRES_DB: keycloak
        POSTGRES_USER: keycloak
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      ports:
        - 5432:5432
  keycloak:
      image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest
      environment:
        DB_VENDOR: POSTGRES
        DB_ADDR: postgres
        DB_DATABASE: keycloak
        DB_USER: keycloak
        DB_SCHEMA: public
        DB_PASSWORD: password
        KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
        KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: admin
      ports:
        - 8080:8080
      depends_on:
        - postgres
```

Example of error it generates:

```
keycloak_1  | 19:18:17,191 FATAL [org.keycloak.services] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) Error during startup: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to connect to database

keycloak_1  | 19:18:17,631 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("subsystem" => "microprofile-metrics-smallrye")]): java.lang.NullPointerException

keycloak_1  | 19:18:17,639 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 46) WFLYSRV0022: Deploy of deployment "keycloak-server.war" was rolled back with no failure message
```

From the error message, it seems like the database isn't generated 1st even though the keyword "depends" is used.

The question is how to fix it/work around it.

Comment: `depends` in the docker-compose file just ensure your db container is started/created first. but it doesn't wait until postgres accept connections/is fully available. So it can either be that postgres is not starting correctly at all or too slow. In both cases you need to verify first that the database is fully operational and only then start keycloak

Comment: @Evil_skunk
Thank you for your response, the database starts, just cannot be fully operational in time, is there a way to delay the start of the 2nd container through heath checks or  other tool?

Answer (score 0):

Since no one answered my question properly, here is the solution I found working using dependencies.
To the postgresql manifest following lines are added:

```
healthcheck:
  test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U keycloak"]
  interval: 10s
  timeout: 5s
  retries: 5
```

and to the keycloak:

```
depends_on:
  postgres-database:
    condition: service_healthy
```